# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) with g++ on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, g++, bin

I was trying to install a new version of g++ and I think I've made a mistake by deleting some executable binaries in usr/bin , so now when I try to install it by synaptic or by doing :
sudo apt-get install g++

```
Errors were encountered during execution:
 g++
 build-essential
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone knows how I can repair my mistake ?